# Using the Intersection Definition of Span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S be a finite set of vectors S = {(1, 0, 1), (2, 1, 3)} where S is a subset of a vector space, $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$, and W is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I know how to compute the $span(S)= \left \{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}v_{i} :c_{i}\epsilon \mathbb{R}, v_{i}\epsilon S\right \}=\left \{ c_{1}(1,0,1)+ c_{2}(2,1,3):c_{1},c_{2}\epsilon \mathbb{R} \right \}=\left \{ (1c_{1}+2c_{2},0c_{1}+1c_{2},1c_{1}+3c_{2}):c_{1},c_{2}\epsilon\mathbb{R} \right \}$

However, I am wanting to use this definition of span to get to that answer: $span(S)=\bigcap_{S\subseteq W\subseteq V} W$. I was thinking of listing all the  subspaces W could be for example $\left \{ {(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})\epsilon \mathbb{R}^{3}: x_{3}=x_{2}+x_{1}} \right \}$. Ultimately, I want to use the second definition to get to that answer and make sense of it.

Comment: You can't list all subspaces $W$ as there's an infinite number of them.

Comment: Subspaces are closed under linear combination, and the span of a set is defined to be the set of all linear combinations of vectors from that set.  So the intersection of all subspaces containing the set is the “minimal” subspace that contains the set.  It contains linear combinations and nothing extra.

Comment: Do two things: 1. Show that the first definition is a subspace containing $S$ and 2. show that any subspace $W$ that contains $S$ much contain all the elements in the span definition.

Comment: @copper.hat What do you mean show the first definition is a subspace containing S and 2?

Comment: @W.G.: Sloppy grammar; "...containing $S$, and 2., ...". Damn pandas.

Comment: Sorry, just in case, my last comment was a reference to the grammar book "Eats, Shoots & Leaves".

Comment: @copper.hat: Why 2 though?

Comment: @W.G.: If $W$ is a subspace that contains $S$ then show that this must contain $\operatorname{sp} S$. Then we must have $\cap_{S \subset W, W \text{ subspace}} W = \operatorname{sp} S$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Are you referring to something like this? $\begin{bmatrix}
w_{1}\\ 
w_{2}\\ 

w_{3}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2 \\ 
 0&1 \\ 
 1&3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1}\\ 

c_{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @W.G.: Ignore my comments, they are correct but irrelevant. I don't see a way of doing what you want in a non contrived way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59251/discussion-between-w-g-and-copper-hat).